# Not sure if Kernel Version correct

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-ace, device-firmware

I recently updated my Samsung GT-S5830 to Gingerbread via Kies. After the update my phone is displaying the kernel version as `2.6.35.7-perf-CL5XXXXX root@DELL 142 #1`. The `X`s are some 5 digit number. Im not sure if this is normal or if theres something wrong (because of the 'root'). Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see how you'd be confused by that.  It doesn't indicate that your phone is rooted, just that the kernel was compiled by the root user (on a DELL build machine, apparently)!  If you look at `/system/build.prop` (probably requires root to look, ha) you'll see some other similar information about the build.  Mine says "jaeyoon.yoon@SEP-05" for the same info.